# AccountKIt LoginActivity Background Image doesn't show up

Tags: android, facebook, android-theme, android-styles

I started implementing AccountKit SDK by Facebook in my application.
In the UI documentation it clearly gives me attribute for the background Image of the theme, but that doesn't work.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android/customizing

Then I tried it with small 100x100 image
which worked.
Any solution why normal Image won't show up as a background
here's my code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="LoginThemeYellow" parent="Theme.AccountKit">
    <item name="com_accountkit_primary_color">#94612D</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_primary_text_color">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_secondary_text_color">#BE8C5B</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_secondary_color">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_status_bar_color">#94612D</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_button_background_color">#94612D</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_button_border_color">#94612D</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_button_disabled_background_color">#e2b382</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_background">@mipmap/horse1</item>

    <item name="com_accountkit_input_accent_color">?attr/com_accountkit_primary_color</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_input_border_color">?attr/com_accountkit_primary_color</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding this item to the style worked for me:

```
<item name="com_accountkit_background_color">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

using account kit version 4.16.1

Comment: Thanks for this answer!! I waste nearly an hour